# How can I begin a string with a number?

Tags: python

I have written the following python project which provides a random output of 20 strings and I have set the limit of it to be less than 100,000 during each run and every string shall be unique.

Now I want to add a line of code that helps me start each output with a number

To make it more simple here is an example:

- Output right now: `AtcaF268d1whnkwiwuniw`
- Output I need: `7atcaF268d1whnkwiwuni`

So each output is a random number.

Here is the code to edit:

```
import random

results = []
while len(results) < 100000:
    result_str = ''.join(
        (random.choice('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789')
            for i in range(20)))
    if result_str not in results:
        results.append(result_str)

with open('string_test.txt','a') as out:
    out.write( '\n'.join(results) )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just generate it separately, I guess.

```
import random

results = []
while len(results) < 100000:
    result_str = random.choice('0123456789') + ''.join((random.choice('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789') for i in range(19)))
    if result_str not in results:
        results.append(result_str)

with open('string_test.txt','a') as out:
    out.write( '\n'.join(results) )
```

Answer (score 1):

You just add the number in front then add 19 more.
By changing your "collection" from `list` to `set` you can avoid the `in` check as well - uniqueness is an inherent quality of sets.

- string constants from the `string` [module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html) makes your code cleaner
- `random.choices()` returns `k` random elements with duplicates as list

```
from string import digits, ascii_letters
from random import choice, choices


results = set()
while len(results) < 100000:
    results.add ( f"{choice(digits)}{''.join(choices(digits+ascii_letters,k=19))}")

with open('string_test.txt','a') as out:
    out.write( '\n'.join(results) )
```